# Multiple xslt tranformations

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xml-parsing

In input i have xml file(it can be 1000 or 100000 files) and i have to convert it to 6 csv files for later saving to the database. My question is how to do this in java more efficient, now i create 6 transformers with different xslt stylesheets and manually transform xml 6 times. I tried do this in one xslt transformation with function: result-document, it works, but in inputmay be more than one xml file and after each transformation data in result files rewrites. My idea collect all data from xml files in csv and then copy it to db tables.

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

Transformer transformer = tf.newTemplates(stylesource).newTransformer();
Transformer transformer2 = tf.newTemplates(stylesource2).newTransformer();
Transformer transformer3 = tf.newTemplates(stylesource3).newTransformer();
Transformer transformer4 = tf.newTemplates(stylesource4).newTransformer();
Transformer transformer5 = tf.newTemplates(stylesource5).newTransformer();
Transformer transformer6 = tf.newTemplates(stylesource6).newTransformer();

DocumentBuilder db = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

public void transformXmlToCsv(String content) throws TransformerException, IOException, SAXException {
    Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(content)));
    Source source = new DOMSource(doc);

    transformer.transform(source, outputTarget);
    transformer2.transform(source, outputTarget2);
    transformer3.transform(source, outputTarget3);
    transformer4.transform(source, outputTarget4);
    transformer5.transform(source, outputTarget5);
    transformer6.transform(source, outputTarget6);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One improvement you could make would be to avoid repeated parsing of the source document by building the input tree once. For example, by building a DOM tree and using a `DOMSource`, or (better if you're using Saxon) by using Saxon interfaces to build the tree once in Saxon's internal format.

Another improvement would be to only create one `TransformerFactory` for everything. Creating a `TransformerFactory` is typically expensive (it involves a search of the classpath) and there's no need to ever create more than one.

It should be easy to fix your problem with `xsl:result-document`. There are many ways of doing it, e.g. by directing the output of each transformation to a different directory, but I can't tell what the best way is without more information.

Comment: Ok, I will create only one instance TransformerFactory. About DomSource I think it will affect performance, in input I have xml files with size 1-10mb and dom load whole file in memory. About result-document if I can append result from multiple transformations to one file it can fix my problem. But I don’t know how to do it.

Comment: The XSLT processor will build a tree in memory anyway. It will probably build a more efficient tree than a DOM, but you only want to build the tree once; the way of doing that depends on the XSLT processor you are using. Doing "append" operations using `xsl:result-document` is an interesting topic and should probably be a new question; the answer is probably going to be product-dependent.

Comment: I have added DOM, performance increased. I am using javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource; may be you know faster implementation? And question about result document is interesting, can we discuss here, how can i append result?

Comment: Does "performance increased" mean time increased or speed increased? You still haven't said which XSLT processor you are using, which is rather essential before talking about performance. As for result-document, I think it merits a new question.

Comment: Speed increased. Process 100000 xml files with 3 threads and streamSoruce spent 20 minutes, with dom 10-12 minutes. Xslt processor is net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl@23941fb4.  Saxon-HE - 9.9.1-6

Comment: Thanks. You should get another speed-up if you switch from DOMSource to Saxon's native tree, but that means departing from pure JAXP API. Replace `TransformerFactory.newInstance()` with `new net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl()`, then build the document using `factory.getConfiguration().buildDocumentTree(streamSource)`; the resulting `TreeInfo` implements `Source` and can be used as input to `transform()`.

Comment: I have changed xslt processor. I am not mentioned change in performance, you can help with another speed ups?

Comment: If you want to engage Saxonica to undertake a performance analysis of this workload, please contact us directly and we can quote you a price.